# How do I generate the .ism and .ismc with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, smooth-streaming

I'm trying to set up a service that will output .ismv files for smooth streaming. 
Currently I'm using the following command to start the transcode:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i <infile> -movflags frag_keyframe -f ismv <outfile>
```

As I understand it I don't need to add `isml` to the `movflags` because I don't want to stream it but the actual output file.

According to the [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-6) I already should use the `empty_moov` and `separate_moof` flags because I'm using the ismv format. This however does not generate the .ism and .ismc file.

There is a part about [smoothstreaming](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#smoothstreaming), but if I use `-f smoothstreaming` ffmpeg won't run.

I did find a win32 binary for `ismindex` which should generate the manifest files, but when I run it I don't get any useful output.

What are the correct parameters for ffmpeg so that it creates all the files at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ismindex [-split] [-ismf] [-n basename] [-path-prefix prefix] [-ismc-prefix prefix] [-output dir] file1 [file2] ...

To generate the manifest files you would do:

```
ismindex -n <basename> input.ismv
```

The `smoothstreaming` muxer accepts a directory as output.

```
ffmpeg [...] -f smoothstreaming <dir>
```